# NetLogo: How to ask to turtles who on the cells except the origin cell?

Tags: netlogo

I want to ask to turtles who on the cells except the origin cell  (x, y) = (0, 0) in one-dimensional cells spaces.
The following is sample code, however, this syntax includes the origin cell (x, y) = (0, 0).

```
ask turtles with [xcor < max-pxcor]
```

Please advice here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do I have it right that you want to `ask` turtles that are not on `patch 0 0`? If so, maybe this will work for you:

```
to setup
  ca
  crt 100 [ move-to one-of patches ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles with [ patch-here != patch 0 0 ] [
    rt random 61 - 30
    fd 1
  ]
  tick  
end
```

**Edit:** If you want to ask turtles not on the origin patch (in this example, 0 0) and turtles not on a patch with `max-pxcor`:

```
to go-2
  ask turtles with [ floor xcor > 0 and xcor < max-pxcor ] [
    rt random 61 - 30
    fd 1
  ]
  tick
end
```

Comment: @goodgest - Not sure that I've understood what you mean. Have a look at the edit above, but if that still doesn't capture what you're after, you may want to edit the question to provide more detail.